# error LNK2019: unsolved external symbol?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cplex

I'm working with Cplex and visual studio 2010. I have added the include and linked the `.lib`. I have a lot of errors like the following:

- Error 1

  ```
  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall IloAlgorithm::extract(class IloModel)const "
  (?extract@IloAlgorithm@@QBEXVIloModel@@@Z) referenced in function
  _main   C:\Users\yasmine\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NursesAllocation\NursesAllocation\NursesAllocation.obj
  ```
- Error 2

  ```
  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall IloCplex::IloCplex(class IloEnv)"
  (??0IloCplex@@QAE@VIloEnv@@@Z) referenced in function
  _main   C:\Users\yasmine\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NursesAllocation\NursesAllocation\NursesAllocation.obj
  ```

Please, can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you add library to project settings? (in linker section)

Comment: Did you add *correct* library?

Comment: I looked at the documentation for cplex, it didn't seem very good. Maybe you didn't do the right thing. Try explaining exactly what you did do when you 'linked the lib'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it including ilocplex.lib to the additional dependencies.
However, I have Cplex for Visual Studio 2008.